# Abrir contato Whats através de href

Tags: android, whatsapp

```
    <a href="intent://send/.  
19994549640#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">
    <img src="img/whatspng.png">
    </a>
```

Quero transformar em uma `intent` dentro do *Android Studio*, porque  assim no navegador ele irá abrir o Whats com o contato mencionado, já no *Android* está difícil de achar.

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma lida aqui na [documentação](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012) do Whatsapp, mas basicamente você precisa fazer desta forma para enviar um texto:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

Comment: preciso de uma chamada via href ao intent do androind, desenvolvendo no android studio

Comment: @EvandroAguiar user [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15931345/2570426) para resolver seu problema.

Comment: eu preciso igual utilizo via site, quando acessado via browser da certinho, queria ver como uma intent abrindo o contato do whats ao clicar no link